# Substraction Between MAX and Count

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the difference between the max quantity of books written by an author and the quantity writed by each author.

```
SELECT  count(book_name) contar, (MAX(C.qty) - count(book_name)) final
FROM (select B.author_id, count(book_name) qty 
     FROM author A ,BOOK B 
     WHERE A.author_id = B.author_id 
     GROUP BY b.author_id) C , 
author A, 
BOOK B 
WHERE A.author_id = B.author_id 
    AND B.author_id=C.Author_id
    AND date_release BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 20 YEAR AND NOW()
GROUP BY c.author_id
HAVING contar > 0
```

As you see there's two tables `BOOK` that has `book_id`, `author_id`, `book_name`, `date_release`, and table `AUTHOR` `author_id`, `author_name`, `author_lastname`, `date_birth`.

I'm getting this results

[image: results]

But I need something like

```
--------+-------+--+
| contar | final |  |
+--------+-------+--+
|      1 |    -4 |  |
|      2 |    -3 |  |
|      5 |     0 |  |
|      1 |    -4 |  |
+--------+-------+--+
```

Comment: Is it correct that the main query only counts books in the last 20 years, but the subquery counts all books?

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: Can you explain what Mac quantity is supposed to be?  Total quantity makes sense to be, but not the max.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `MAX(C.qty)` is being calculated per-author, because the query has `GROUP BY c.author_id`. You need to calculate this total just once for the entire subquery.

There's also no need to join with `AUTHOR` when getting the count of books per author, since the author ID is in `BOOK`.

```
SELECT  count(book_name) contar, (max_qty - count(book_name)) final
FROM (SELECT MAX(qty) AS max_qty
      FROM (select count(book_name) qty 
            FROM BOOK B 
            GROUP BY b.author_id) t
     ) C 
CROSS JOIN author A
JOIN book B ON A.author_id = B.author_id 
WHERE date_release BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 20 YEAR AND NOW()
GROUP BY A.author_id
```

And there's no need for `HAVING contar > 0`, because authors with no books will not be included in the `JOIN`.

Comment: I have to put an alias to the 2nd subquery, but its ok! THANKS

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I made each number equal to a variable and then subtracted those variables. The variables will come out as columns however.

```
SELECT  count(book_name) contar, 
        @max:=( MAX(C.qty) ), 
        @bookcount:=( count(book_name) ), 
        @final:= @max-@bookcount
FROM (select B.author_id, 
             count(book_name) qty 
      FROM author A , BOOK B 
      WHERE A.author_id = B.author_id 
      GROUP BY b.author_id) C , 
      author A, 
      BOOK B 
WHERE A.author_id = B.author_id 
  AND B.author_id = C.Author_id 
  AND date_release BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 20 YEAR 
                       AND NOW()
GROUP BY c.author_id
HAVING contar > 0
```

Comment: can you use set in the select?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza you are right. I was thinking like a stored procedure!

Comment: @CamiloCipagauta try now. I made an error by putting set in there. It should work now.

Comment: I try fix it , but your parenthesis doesnt match.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza they should be all set now. I set it up like the parenthesis and the variables in this statement I made a while ago: http://pastebin.com/Ty1KHuEJ

Comment: You have to be carefull with the use of [variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)  `However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.`